# kendo scheduler cell uid value comes null

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, scheduler

hi to all i am new in kendo scheduler i want get uid of last cell of last row when user hit end key press so please can any one help me to tell why i get null value of cell uid .thanks in advance .

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 35) {
        var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
        var element = scheduler.view().content.find("tr:last td:last");
        var slot = scheduler.slotByElement(element);
        alert(slot);
    }               
});
```

Comment: Does any other variable (`scheduler`, `element`) contain any attributes or all `undefined`?

Comment: else if(event.keyCode == 35){
    // alert("hello end key");
    
    let  scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
                let element = scheduler.view();
    let abc= element.content.find("tr:last td:last");
               let slot = scheduler.slotByElement(abc);
                    
     alert(slot);

Comment: slot is undefine

Comment: scheduler also undefine

Comment: Can you post up your `html`? And also post up where you are initialising the `scheduler` control?

Comment: no man i am in office due to security i m unable to send code.

Comment: No problem, I made up a small example which hopefully has everything you need

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a small [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/aTome) example. This will log the last element in the `scheduler` to the console when the `End` key is pressed.

[image: Console log output]

**EDIT**
If `scheduler` is coming back as `undefined` as you mentioned in one of your comments, it may be because of differences between the `div` id and the `selector`. E.g.

`<div id="scheduler"></div>`

`var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");`

Comment: scheduler not become undefine but slot become still null

Comment: Are you using the same code as in the example? Including `console.log(slot)`. If your code is the same as the example, I cannot see how it would be `null`

Comment: yes me also use the same code even just copy and paste but its become null yet. whatever issue is there once i solved i put here code.

Comment: error comes [ts] Property 'content' does not exist on type 'SchedulerView'

Comment: Perhaps check that you are using a jQuery version [compatible with the version of Kendo controls you are using](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites#supported-jquery-versions)

Comment: 2.2.3 i ma using